# Why my pagedList is not updated via LiveData method .observe?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I have a Dao with this method.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expense WHERE date BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd")
    fun getExpensesBetweenTheDate(dateStart: Calendar, dateEnd: Calendar):
DataSource.Factory<Int, Expense>
```

My repository get Dao and create LiveData> object.

```
fun getExpensesBetweenTheDate(startDay: Calendar, endDay: Calendar): LiveData<PagedList<Expense>> {
        val factory = expenseDao.getExpensesBetweenTheDate(startDay, endDay)
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(30)
            .setMaxSize(200)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .build()
        return LivePagedListBuilder(factory, config)
            .build()
    }
```

My ViewModel get repository and create a variable.

```
val expenses = repository.getExpensesBetweenTheDate(startCalendar, endCalendar)
```

Finally, MainActivity observes on LiveData.

```
viewModel.expenses.observe(this, Observer(simpleExpenseAdapter::submitList))
```

All working fine, but when I try to add a new record to the database, it appears there not immediately, but after restarting the application. Similar code without a paging library works well. Maybe i do something wrong. Just in case, I give below the code of the adapter, viewHolder and layout.

Adapter.

```
class ExpenseAdapter : PagedListAdapter<Expense, ExpenseViewHolder>(EXPENSE_COMPARATOR) {

    companion object {
        private val EXPENSE_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Expense>() {

            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Expense, newItem: Expense): Boolean {
                return oldItem.expenseId == newItem.expenseId
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Expense, newItem: Expense): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExpenseViewHolder {
        return ExpenseViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExpenseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val expenseItem = getItem(position)
        if (expenseItem != null) holder.bind(expenseItem)
    }
}
```

ViewHolder.

```
class ExpenseViewHolder(binding: ExpenseElementSimpleBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    private val mBinding = binding

    init {
        mBinding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(it.context, ShowExpenseActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("expense", mBinding.expense)
            it.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): ExpenseViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ExpenseElementSimpleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            return ExpenseViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }

    fun bind(item: Expense) {
        mBinding.apply {
            expense = item
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

Layout.

```
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
                name="expense"
                type="com.example.budgetplanning.data.model.Expense"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:text="@{expense.description}"
                tools:text="Gasoline"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(expense.amount)}"
                tools:text="123"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: The problem with updating the list was the incorrect definition of the transmitted values of the Calendar type to viewModel variable "expenses".
The rest of the code worked correctly. Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the simpleExpenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after the the submitList

This is happening because when you are calling **simpleExpenseAdapter::submitList** is equivalent to call **simpleExpenseAdapter:submitList()** when the list diff is not called at this time. So, you have to notify that the list has changed.

Or so, you can pass the new list as a parameter like:

```
viewModel.expenses.observe(this, Observer<YourObjectListened> {
    simpleExpenseAdapter.submitList(it)
})
```

Comment: No. Here's my code. `viewModel.expenses.observe(this, Observer<PagedList<Expense>> {
            simpleExpenseAdapter.submitList(it)
        })`. am i doing right?

Comment: Even if using notifyDataSetChanged after the submitList?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#submitList%28kotlin.collections.MutableList%29

Comment: Unfortunately notify does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [toLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/package-summary.html#(androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory).toLiveData(androidx.paging.PagedList.Config,%20androidx.paging.toLiveData.Key,%20androidx.paging.PagedList.BoundaryCallback,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) with original example from [Paging library overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)